# Why do I get no method error when using 'grouped_collection_select'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

When I'm loading edit page for User it shows this error. Why?

In my models I have models such as

- User (This model has one UserProfile)
- UserProfile (This model belongs to User, and has one Country and one Prefecture)
- Country (This model belongs to UserProfile, and has many Prefectures)
- Prefecture (This model belongs to Country and UserProfile)

**error**

> undefined method `name' for #

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.fields_for :user_profile do |profile_form| %>
  <%= profile_form.label :country_id %><br />
  <%= profile_form.collection_select :country_id, Country.order(:name_en), :id, :name_en, include_blank: true %>

  <%= profile_form.label :prefecture_id, "State or Province" %><br />
  <%= profile_form.grouped_collection_select :prefecture_id, Country.order(:name_en), :prefectures, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
<% end %>
```

**models/country.rb**

> has_many :prefectures

**models/prefectures.rb**

> belongs_to :country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<%= profile_form.grouped_collection_select :prefecture_id,Country.order(:name_en),:prefectures, :name_en, :id, :name,include_blank: true %>
```